# Linking to Apple Maps, set directions to "Walking"

Tags: cordova, apple-maps

I link to Apple Maps from my hybrid Phonegap application.

Using the following link works fine:

```
<a data-role="button" href="maps:daddr=Lilleakerveien+16+Oslo&saddr=Current+Location" data-rel="external">Vis veibeskrivelse</a>
```

Maps is opened as expected.

But how can I force the directions to be based on walking?

According to the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html) there is a "type" parameter, but I can't find the options anywhere.

Comment: The type I believe you're referring to is the map type.  Not the directions type.  From the docs you linked, it even says that the `daddr` and `saddr` are used for generating **driving directions**. So I'm not sure if it's even possible to have the directions to walking.  I could be wrong though...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible according to the official Apple docs anyway.

[Drew B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1775295/drew-b) is correct, the type parameter (which is a "t" in the url) is for the type of map.